# Как найти квадратный корень? в javascript без Math.sqrt

Tags: javascript

```js
// у меня не получается


function sum(num1) {
    if (isNaN(num1) ){
        return "Please enter a number"
    }
    var num2 = num1 / 2;
    var result = num2;
    num1 = result * num2;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        result = num1 / num2;
    }
    return result;
}
var result = sum (25);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const sqrt = value => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= value; i++) {
    if (i * i === value) return i;
  }
  
  return 'this number has no integer root';
};

console.log(sqrt(148225));
console.log(sqrt(9));
console.log(sqrt(25));
console.log(sqrt(1));
console.log(sqrt(4));
console.log(sqrt(39.283));
```

Comment: для оптимизации, достаточно `value/2`, а не просто `value`, ибо очевидно, что `value-1` не может быть квадратным корнем `value`

Comment: писали бы уже сразу `i*i <= value` что уж там... А так корень из 4 весело извлекать) или из 1.

Comment: вы мне очень помогли